# What does this Ruby code using inject method do?

Tags: ruby

```
class Array
    def sum(start = 0)
        inject(start, &:+)
    end
end
```

Please explain me the use of this code.
Test case with input and output will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: No. I am reading a book where i saw this piece of code. The author didnt give any explaination of the code. Hence the question!

Comment: have you read [the documentation for inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) and tried out the code?

Comment: Found this video: https://vimeo.com/51579832 !

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#comment17104_253896

Answer (score 1):

It sums up all the elements that are kept inside you array. `start` is a value to which sum is added. for example for array `foo = [1, 4]; foo.inject(10, &:+)` will return 15 (10 + 1 + 4).
`&:+` is telling what operation should be called on each element in array;
it's the same as you would give your own callback for example

```
foo.inject(10) do |current_sum, current_element|
  current_sum = current_sum + current_element #can be written current_sum += current_element
  current_sum
end
```

Comment: FWIW `current_sum + current_element` is all that is necessary in the body of the block.